# GTK# FileChooserButton crashes app under Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows, monodevelop, gtk#

This simple GTK SharpApp works in Linux, but the executable crashes under
Windows 7 (which has GTK libraries installed via the mono supplied gtk-sharp-2.12.26.msi
installer). exe built with MonoDevelop Version 5.7.1 (build 269), Mono/.NET 4.5
target.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Gtk;
using System.Linq;
using Gdk;
using System.IO;
using GLib;

namespace fcbtest
{

    public class SharpApp : Gtk.Window
    {
        public SharpApp () : base ("FilechooserButton Test")


      {
            BorderWidth = 8;

            SetSizeRequest(80,80);
            SetPosition (WindowPosition.Center);
            DeleteEvent += delegate {Application.Quit ();};

            VBox vbox = new VBox (false, 4);
            FileChooserButton fcb = new FileChooserButton ("Log Folder",
FileChooserAction.SelectFolder);
            vbox.PackStart(fcb,true,true,0);

            Add(vbox);

            ShowAll();
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            Application.Init();
            new SharpApp();
            Application.Run();
        }
    } 
}
```

Under Windows 7 an immediate exception is thrown when clicking on a directory
shown by the button:

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        .NET Runtime
Date:          3/2/2015 3:44:13 PM
Event ID:      1026
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      win7vbox
Description:
Application: fcb-test.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
Stack:
   at Gtk.Application.gtk_main()
   at Gtk.Application.Run()
   at fcbtest.SharpApp.Main()

Log Name:      Application
Source:        Application Error
Date:          3/2/2015 3:44:13 PM
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: (100)
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      win7vbox
Description:
Faulting application name: fcb-test.exe, version: 1.0.5539.28221, time stamp:
0x54f4d8da
Faulting module name: libgtk-win32-2.0-0.dll, version: 2.24.22.0, time stamp:
0x3ea43e4d
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x001a4ca6
Faulting process id: 0x504
Faulting application start time: 0x01d05531fe94d941
Faulting application path: X:\lineuptool\fcb-test.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files
(x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin\libgtk-win32-2.0-0.dll
Report Id: 43eb9471-c125-11e4-bb3d-080027a4cf05
```

Is there a fix or workaround available?

Comment: have you stepped through the code to see exactly what line it errors on..? I am wondering if it errors after the `Application.Init()` call in your main

Comment: This is actually a Xamarin recommended test example to illustrate the problem. My GUI app is actually more complex. From this information it's pretty clear that the exception is originating in libgtk-win32-2.0-0.dll which is not user code. FWIW, I even tried "corflags /32BIT+", but the exception is still thrown.

Comment: Found a workaround. Instead of the FileChooserButton I use an ordinary Button which launches a "folder chooser" dialog via the clicked handler. Not as elegant/efficient as a single button that does everything, but it works.

Comment: sounds good.. as long as it works for you there's nothing wrong with coming up with your own `work around`